# How to use a setter to set a value of complex property

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

I have two base classes.

```
public class IValue
{
  public dynamic Value { get; set; }

  public dynamic Type { get; set; }
}

public class IParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Required { get; set; }

    public IValue ValueObject
    {
        get { return _value.Value; }
        set { _value.Value = value; } 
    }

    private IValue _value { get; set; }
}

public class MyParm : IParameter
{ 

}
```

Now in order to set the ValuesObject of the MyParam Class, I should be able to use this line.

```
MyParam.ValueObject = "";
```

but instead I have to use this line

```
MyParam.ValueObject.Value = "";
```

Nobody ever needs to get the Type, the value is all that matters, the Type is there for the system. Is there a way to accomplish setting the ValueObject.Value and getting it, without explicitly saying .Value?

Comment: Your `public IValue ValueObject` should be `public dynamic ValueObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
public class IParameter
    {
        public IParameter()
        {
            _value = new IValue();
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Required { get; set; }

        public dynamic Value
        {
            get { return _value.Value; }
            set
            {
                _value.Value = value;
            }
        }

        private IValue _value { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in order to set the Values of the MyParam Class, you will be able to use this line.

```
MyParam.Value = "";
```